# CodeIgniter form_open() using incorrect base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I had been developing a system with it set up as `someolddomain.somewhere.com` and after development was completed, I copied the entire CI project code base into a new folder, setup the new virtual host config in Apache to point to the new directory path and domain, and changed

```
$config['base_url'] = 'someolddomain.somewhere.com'
```

in application/config/config.php to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'somenewdomain.somewhere.com'
```

however when I use CI's 
form_open, the action on the forms is still coming through as `someolddomain.somewhere.com`. I've even tried setting it as `$config['base_url'] = ''` but form_open is still using the old domain.

I've grepped recursively through the entire CI directory structure looking for "someolddomain", but it's not present.

So where is it coming from?

I know I can just use straight html and set the form action, but I would really like to know why this is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your .htaccess looks OK and you can't seem to find anything else check to see if the pages are being cached.  If they're cached you can force a refresh by deleting the files in application/cache folder.

Comment: The only two files in application/cache are .htaccess and an index.html which imitates a 404 error.

Comment: Possible Apache could be caching it too.  If not could you post an example of a form_open() that's not working?

Comment: ```
<?php
$attributes = array('class' => 'form-signin', 'role' => 'form');
echo validation_errors(); 
echo form_open('login/login', $attributes);
echo form_error('userName');
?>
```

Comment: I can't replicate the issue you're seeing.  Every way I try it works properly.  I would check the Virtual Hosts config and make sure that looks OK.  It might help to empty the project out of your somenewdomain.somewhere.com and put a fresh copy of codeigniter there with a clean controller/view using the form_open() helper.  If you're still seeing the same behavior then at least you can rule out the code being the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for looking Jason. I may try that at some point, but for now I think I will just use HTML <form> tags rather than CI's form_open method for the sake of saving time. Not a big enough issue for me to waste more time on it when I know HTML works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused by the configuration of

`$application_folder = '/var/www/somewhere/someolddomain/application'`

inside of public/index.php.

I had totally forgotten about this config variable and as an aside, it would make more sense for it to be in config.php or some other file inside application/config at least.

Once I changed the path to point to the correct folder, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Config.php at system/core loads

```
$this->set_item('base_url', $base_url);
```

The form_helper at system/helpers use:

```
 $action = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
```

Solution:

```
$config['site_url'] = "NEW DOMAIN"
```